# Antibiotics mixed with yogurt on Sinclac containing bacteria cultures?

Tags: medicines, rat

I was wondering, since antibiotics fight against bacteria, then if I give my rat an antibiotic mixed with yogurt (containing for instance Lactobacillus bulgaricus) or Nestle Sinlac (containing Bifidobacterium lactis) does it make my antibiotic weaker since there are more bacteria to fight?

Answer (score 3):

The short answer to this is: the bacteria in the food do not affect the concentration of antibiotics, but there are some antibiotics that are influenced by milk and milk products, so read the information on the package.

Some antibiotics are to be given with more fluid than other types.